# Facing Error connecting to databasein node js ssh tunnel configuration (aws ec2 &rds)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, ssh-tunnel

I have connected pg admin with the private rds using ssh tunnel. Currently ec2 security group accepts all traffic.
However, I still get a timeout error when I try to connect my database from my local machine

tunnel.js (tunnel.js and private key are resided in the same folder)

```
const { createTunnel } = require ('tunnel-ssh');

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require("path");
require('dotenv').config();

async function createSSHTunnel(srcAddr = process.env.EC_HOST, srcPort = 22) {
    console.log(" ssh tunnel started")
    const tunnelOptions = {
        autoClose: true,
    };

    const serverOptions = {
        port: 12345,
    };

    const sshOptions = {
        host: process.env.EC2_HOST,
        port: 22,
        username: "ec2-user",
         privateKey: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,"dev-jump-box.pem"))
       
    };

    file =  fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,"dev-jump-box.pem"))
    console.log(file)

    const forwardOptions = {
    srcAddr: 'localhost',
    srcPort: 12345,
    dstAddr:  process.env.DB_HOST,
    dstPort:5432,
};

    try {
        console.log(" try tunnel")
        await createTunnel(
            tunnelOptions,
            serverOptions,
            sshOptions,
            forwardOptions
        );
        console.log(" try tunnel ended")
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.code === "EADDRINUSE") {
            // Assume port is uniquely used by SSH tunnel, so existing connection can be reused
            console.log(`Returning existing SSH tunnel on ${srcAddr}:${srcPort}.`);
            return { srcAddr, srcPort };
        } else {
            throw error;
        }
    }
    
    console.log(`SSH tunnel successfully created on ${srcAddr}:${srcPort}.`);
    
    return { srcAddr, srcPort };
}

module.exports = { createSSHTunnel };
```

database.js

```
const Pool = require("pg").Pool;
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const { createSSHTunnel } = require ('./tunnel');
//const Tunnel = require('tunnel-ssh')
dotenv.config()
console.log(" "+process.env.DB_DATABASE)


const { srcAddr, srcPort } = createSSHTunnel(); 
const pool  = new Pool({
    
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    user:process.env.DB_USER,
    password:process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database:process.env.DB_DATABASE,
    port: process.5432,
    max: 80,
    connectionTimeoutMillis:60000,
    idleTimeoutMillis:500
  });

  module.exports = pool;
```

attachDbclientMiddleware

```
const pool = require('../Util/database');

exports.attachDbClient = async(req, res, next) =>{
    pool.connect()
        .then(client => {
            req.dbClient = client; // Attach client to request
            next();
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error('Error connecting to database:', err);
            res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
        });
        console.log("client ")
      
}
```

Terminal Output-

**UPDATE**

got an error -

Error connecting to database: Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
at Connection. (/home/tahmid/Projects/mobile_dev_back/mobile_backend_EIDPOINT/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:132:73)
at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:641:28)
at Connection.emit (node:events:527:28)
at Connection.emit (node:domain:475:12)
at Socket. (/home/tahmid/Projects/mobile_dev_back/mobile_backend_EIDPOINT/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:57:12)
at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
at Socket.emit (node:domain:475:12)
at TCP. (node:net:688:12)

Comment: It requires special privileges to listen to ports below 1024.  Change that to 2022 - or really any port above 1024.

Comment: after using this command - 
**sudo setcap cap_net_bind_service=+ep /home/lib/.nvm/versions/node/v17.6.0/bin/node**

But then got a new error - 


Error connecting to database: Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
    at Connection.<anonymous> 
Updated in the post.